# adding only OneHotEncoding to specific columns into sklearn pipeline wihtout using ColumnTransformer

Tags: python, scikit-learn

sklearn == 0.24.2

While creating multiple versions of my decision tree regressor I want to try one with ordinal encoder and one with onehotencoder.

Trying to use pipeline however wondering if there is a way to apply OHE on specific columns when being used in Pipeline.

Right now only way I could add OHE and ordinal Encoding to certain columns in pipeline is by

```
tree = DecisionTreeRegressor()

ohe = Pipeline(steps=[("ohe", OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"))])
col_transformer = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[("cate", ohe, cate_cols)],
                                    remainder='drop')

dt_reg_ohe = Pipeline([("col_transform", col_transformer) ,("DT_reg", tree)])
```

This works fine however I don't see the point in having `ColumnTransformer` therefore hoping to do the same without it. Same goes for when I use ordinal encoding.

as commented by @Ben Reiniger and after researching, below seems more cleaner.

```
ohe = make_column_transformer(
     (OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'), cate_cols),
      remainder='passthrough')
```

Comment: I recommend implementing your custom `OneHotEncoder` class, the only change you have to make is in `__init__` function to use `dataframe` instead of `np.ndarray`

Comment: This is precisely the purpose of `ColumnTransformer`.

Comment: @BenReiniger Oh thanks! It is cumbersome to use wrap ohe with pipeline which is wrapped again by ColumnTransformer, therefore thought there might be another method.

Comment: You don't need the intermediate pipeline, if all you want to do to the categorical columns is one-hot encode.